# Get the type of a file in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, file

I succeeded to find the extended file type of a specified file ( JPEG image, TIFF Image, ...) but I am looking for something more generic that can categorize files in "big cathegories" like images, moovies, text files, ...
It there a way to acheive this in cocoa (or objective-c) ?

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You could use [Uniform Type Identifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_intro/understand_utis_intro.html). Since UTIs are organised into hierarchies, one possibility is to check whether the preferred UTI for a given file conforms to a top-level UTI, e.g. `public.image` for images or `public.movie` for movies. The Core Services framework includes functions that operate on UTIs as well as constants representing known UTIs.

For instance, working on file name extensions:

```
NSString *file = @"…"; // path to some file
CFStringRef fileExtension = (CFStringRef) [file pathExtension];
CFStringRef fileUTI = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, fileExtension, NULL);

if (UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI, kUTTypeImage)) NSLog(@"It's an image");
else if (UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI, kUTTypeMovie)) NSLog(@"It's a movie");
else if (UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI, kUTTypeText)) NSLog(@"It's text");

CFRelease(fileUTI);
```

If you have a MIME type instead of a file name extension, you can use `kUTTagClassMIMEType` instead of `kUTTagClassFilenameExtension`.

For a list of known UTIs, see [this document](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html).

Comment: If you're like me and having problems getting the file extension to conform to the correct UTI, make sure you don't prepend the file extension with a period! You should be passing "jpg" and NOT ".jpg"!

Comment: Unfortunately the check for the UTI seems to work only with some video types / files. It works fine with MP4 containers (for example), but it doesn't work with MKV containers. `UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag` returns a dynamic type beginning with `dyn` prefix when it cannot find a suitable UTI (so for MKV, for example).

Comment: hello what type equal to doc/docx? Thanks

Answer (score 14):

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] typeOfFile:pathToFile error:nil]
```

Answer (score 6):

Example to check whether a path is an image type, can be change to match other UTI classes.  Note the Tech Note Technical Q&A QA1518 uses FSPathMakeRef which is now deprecated to get the uti via LSCopyItemAttributes - the NSWorkspace solution above is the best way to get the UTI then you just need to add code to compare with a list of UTIs: (the matching array can be pre allocated and initialised/released elsewhere if desired)

```
- (BOOL)isImageFile:(NSString*)filePath
{
/* get an array of utis to match against, this gets supported CG/NS image formats */

CFArrayRef supportedTypes = CGImageSourceCopyTypeIdentifiers();
CFIndex    typeCount      = CFArrayGetCount(supportedTypes);

/* get the uti of the filepath and check against the list with the UTI API */

BOOL isImage     = NO;
NSString * uti   = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] typeOfFile:filePath error:nil];

if ( uti != nil){
    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < typeCount; i++)
    {
        CFStringRef supportedUTI = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(supportedTypes, i);
        if (UTTypeConformsTo(supportedUTI, CFSTR("public.image")))
        {
            if (UTTypeConformsTo((CFStringRef)uti, supportedUTI))
            {
                isImage = YES;
                break;
            }
        }
    } // i
}
/* clean up */
CFRelease(supportedTypes);
return isImage;
}
```

Comment: Very handy, thanks. And for anyone interested in a Swift version, [here's a link to a URL extension](https://github.com/toddalton/SwiftFileImageCheck/blob/master/ImageFileCheck)

Answer (score 6):

You can also determine the image type *without* relying on the path extension with CGImageSource (part of the ImageIO framework).

The following example uses a file URL, but you can also create an image source from a CFDataRef.

```
CFStringRef typeOfImageAtURL(NSURL *imageURL) {
    const void * keys[] = { kCGImageSourceShouldCache };
    const void * values[] = { kCFBooleanFalse };
    CFDictionaryRef options = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, keys, values, 1, NULL, NULL);
    CGImageSourceRef imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)imageURL, options);
    CFStringRef imageType = CGImageSourceGetType(imageSource);
    CFRelease(options);
    CFRelease(imageSource);
    return imageType;
}
```

The return value will be a constant that you can compare with the uniform type identifier values declared in CoreServices/MobileCoreServices (e.g., kUTTypeJPEG, kUTTypeGIF, etc).

The icing on the cake: you can pass in an optional "hint" UTI if you have reason to anticipate one file type or another. Combine this approach with Bavarious' and you'll have a lean, mean image format detection machine.

Answer (score 3):

This will get the 'kind' of file.

```
+ (NSString *)humanReadableFileType:(NSString *)path{
    NSString *kind = nil;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[path stringByExpandingTildeInPath]];
    LSCopyKindStringForURL((CFURLRef)url, (CFStringRef *)&kind);
    return kind ? [kind autorelease] : @"";
}
```

*Source*: http://importantshock.wordpress.com/2007/01/07/cocoa-snippet-finding-a-files-kind/#post-19

Comment: This is the one I am using and it returns "JPEG image", "MP3 Audio" instead of "image", "audio","movie" , ....

Comment: LSCopyKindStringForURL is now deprecated. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37765413/how-do-you-get-the-finder-kind-for-a-file-in-2016#37765537) was helpful for me.