# Check NSURL for UTI / file type

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, video

I'm building an app that allows users to drop videos onto it. Given a list of dropped NSURL*s how do I make sure each one conforms to the `public.movie` UTI type?

If I had an `NSOpenPanel`, I would just use `openPanel.allowedFileTypes = @[@"public.movie"];` and Cocoa would take care of it for me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This should work:

```
NSWorkspace *workspace = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];

for (NSURL *url in urls) {
    NSString *type;
    NSError *error;
    if ([url getResourceValue:&type forKey:NSURLTypeIdentifierKey error:&error]) {
        if ([workspace type:type conformsToType:@"public.movie"]) {
            // the URL points to a movie; do stuff here
        }
    } else {
        // handle error
    }
}
```

(You can also use `UTTypeConformsTo()` instead of the `NSWorkspace` method.)

Comment: How do you do this on iOS? ```NSWorkspace``` requires ```AppKit``` which is only available on ```macOS```. Thanks.

Comment: Found the answer to my own question - for iOS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5815629/1598906

Answer (score 1):

Swift version:

```
do {
    var value: AnyObject?
    try url.getResourceValue(&value, forKey:NSURLTypeIdentifierKey)
    if let type = value as? String {
        if UTTypeConformsTo(type, kUTTypeMovie) {
        ...
        }
    }
}
catch {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 version:

```
if let resourceValues = try? localUrl.resourceValues(forKeys: [URLResourceKey.typeIdentifierKey]) {
    if let typeId = resourceValues.typeIdentifier {
        if UTTypeConformsTo(type, kUTTypeMovie) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```