# iphone - how to check if the file is a directory , audio , video or image?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsfilemanager

Following my program shows contents of Documents directory and is displayed in a tableView .
But the Documents directory contains some directories , some audio , some video , and some images etc .

```
NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
fileType = @"" ;
NSString *subDirectoryPath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileType];
NSLog(@"path : %@",subDirectoryPath);
files  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:subDirectoryPath error:nil]];
NSLog(@"files ::::: %@ ",[files description]);
```

So , I want to check if file is directory then it directory image can be shown in the cell's imageView . Same for audio , video and image .

I searched in NSFileManager classReference , but dint get a solution .

**How to do this ?**

Comment: See [my answer for Swift 4.2 and iOS 12](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54160565/1966109) that shows up to 4 different ways to check if a URL represents a file or a directory.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**Sample Code :**

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *directory = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath: documentsDirectory];
BOOL isDirectory;
for (NSString *item in directory){
    BOOL fileExistsAtPath = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:item isDirectory:&isDirectory];
    if (fileExistsAtPath) {
       if (isDirectory)
       {
           //It's a Directory.
       }
    }
    if ([[item pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"png"]) {
       //This is Image File with .png Extension
    }
}
```

---

You can also use [**Uniform Type Identifiers**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html) as explained by **Bavarious** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5815629/1603072).

**Sample Code :**

```
NSString *file = @"…"; // path to some file
CFStringRef fileExtension = (CFStringRef) [file pathExtension];
CFStringRef fileUTI = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, fileExtension, NULL);

if (UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI, kUTTypeImage)) NSLog(@"It's an image");
else if (UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI, kUTTypeMovie)) NSLog(@"It's a movie");
else if (UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI, kUTTypeText)) NSLog(@"It's text");

CFRelease(fileUTI);
```

Comment: if there is no extension means that is folder

Comment: what if audio file...vin...? because there is multiple extension audio file then what we can do..?

Comment: @NitinGohel: Hey Bro, I think he has to compare all those Extensions, I guess !!!

Comment: yup may be but i just want to know can u plz explain for me it's for my understanding plz bro..

Comment: @NitinGohel: Check that link , I have added in my Answer.

Comment: @NitinGohel: Thx. Have you heard about it or used it ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31866/discussion-between-nitin-gohel-and-vin)

Comment: That first piece of code is incorrect. The `if (fileExistsAtPath)` needs another test nested inside it: `if (isDirectory) { _here_ you know it's a folder }`

Comment: @BasilBourque: I just forgot that part at that time. Resolved now. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  "item" is just a string with the last path component.  Instead use :
`NSString * path  = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:item];


        BOOL fileExistsAtPath = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:&isDirectory];`

Comment: @Bhavin
Can you share the swift syntax using `UniformTypeIdentifiers`, The `UIType` does not seem to have any initializer `UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag`

Answer (score 3):

Look at the `NSURL` class. You can for example see if the url is a file url by saying `isFileUrl`.

Additionally you can get the last component of the url (usually the file name) by doing:

```
NSString *filename = [[url path] lastPathComponent];
```

These can help you do what you need, but more importantly look at the `NSURL` documentation.

Comment: +1 for an string/path answer that doesn't rely on `fileExistsAtPath()` (which is blocked by the Sandbox). Answer would be improved by the expected value for `lastPathComponent`... does an empty string == a folder?

Answer (score 3):

Just in case of image file type

```
-(BOOL)isImageSource:(NSURL*)URL
{
    CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)URL, NULL);
    NSString *UTI = (__bridge NSString*)CGImageSourceGetType(source);
    CFRelease(source);

    CFArrayRef mySourceTypes = CGImageSourceCopyTypeIdentifiers();
    NSArray *array = (__bridge NSArray*)mySourceTypes;
    CFRelease(mySourceTypes);

    return [array containsObject:UTI];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For any Swift lovers, coming to this question trying to check if a file is a directory here you go:

```
///
/// Check if NSURL is a directory
///
internal func fileIsDir(fileURL: NSURL) -> Bool {
    var isDir: ObjCBool = false;
    fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(fileURL.path!, isDirectory: &isDir)
    return Bool(isDir);
}

///
/// Check if a path is a directory
///
internal func fileIsDir(path: String) -> Bool {
    var isDir: ObjCBool = false;
    fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(path, isDirectory: &isDir)
    return Bool(isDir);
}
```

(Note that I tried doing `return isDir as Bool` but it didn't work. But the above Bool initiation seems to work.)

Comment: not sure if this is a new api in swift 3. I did `return isDir.boolValue`

Answer (score 3):

Updated Evdzhan's answer for Swift 4.0:

```
//
// Check if NSURL is a directory
//
func fileIsDir(fileURL: NSURL) -> Bool {
    var isDir: ObjCBool = false;
    FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path!, isDirectory: &isDir)
    return isDir.boolValue
}

//
// Check if a path is a directory
//
func fileIsDir(path: String) -> Bool {
    var isDir: ObjCBool = false;
    FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path, isDirectory: &isDir)
    return isDir.boolValue
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you really want to be sure it is an image

```
if let _ =  UIImage(contentsOfFile: url.path){// is image}
```

or NSImage on a Mac

Comment: This was the cleanest solution :) Thanks for sharing. In my case I was able to even use it with the raw data `let _ = UIImage(data: data)`