# Most reliable way to determine if URL is a directory?

Tags: ios, url, filesystems

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54160565/9917619) gives a good answer, but the question did not specify which is the 'most reliable' way. For instance `fileExistsAtPath` has the following documentation.

> Attempting to predicate behavior based on the current state of the
>   file system or a particular file on the file system is not
>   recommended. Doing so can cause odd behavior or race conditions. It’s
>   far better to attempt an operation (such as loading a file or creating
>   a directory), check for errors, and handle those errors gracefully
>   than it is to try to figure out ahead of time whether the operation
>   will succeed. For more information on file-system race conditions, see [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/RaceConditions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002585).

The property `hasDirectoryPath` does not have any warnings in it's documentation. In fact, the documentation for it is pretty sparse.

So I'm now confused, because surely the above warning should say "use `hasDirectoryPath` instead of this".

Comment: [Using URL's hasDirectoryPath property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54160565/5933733)

Comment: Why have you given me this link? It's the same link I reference in my question.

Comment: @Jonesy: The usage really depends on how your app intends to use it; if you are using it for any such scenario where a race condition could create a vector for an attack then I'd say not to use it.

Comment: Thanks for response. Would be good if you could elaborate a little more and maybe give your response as an answer, instead of a comment (might eventually accept the answer if community upvotes).