# Find video extension

Tags: ios, parsing, video

I have a video document which is uploaded on server . The name of that document does not contain any extension.
I have to download that document (which is actually a video file) from the server and play it.
I need to know how do I get the extension of that file. I do not have it specified in my URL.

its just like **/var/mobile/Applications/B18D9BE8-6E1D-43F0-8240-A909B9A27F7C/Documents/XXX/docdata/ABC/XYZ**

XYZ is the document which I want to play. It is actally a video file which is saved on the server.

In Android we do something like parse URI. DO we have anything similar like this in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

a general approach. Have a look at the meta-data of the file to determine which vidoe type it is. This should be provided at the file itself.

Perhaps this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5815629/1933185

Comment: It does not work. It gives me dyn.adq8u as fileUTI. But does not print any log. Do you have any info about dyn.adq8u?

Comment: No. Basic idea was to get sort of this information http://superuser.com/a/595205, so that you can see what kind of video it is. i.e. format, codec, etc

Answer (score 0):

```
The following solution worked for me. Hope it help others as well.

        NSString* fullPath = [yourpath stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
        NSURL* fileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fullPath];
        NSURLRequest* fileUrlRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:fileUrl cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed timeoutInterval:.1];

        NSError* error = nil;
        NSURLResponse* response = nil;
        NSData* fileData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:fileUrlRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];

        NSString* mimeType = [response MIMEType];
        NSArray *components = [mimeType componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
        NSString *query = [components lastObject]; //gives the extension
```

This query is the file extension. Your can put an if/else or switch to perform operation based on your extension.

```
        if ([query isEqualToString:@"mp4"]) {
             yourpath = [yourpath stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"mp4"];
        }
        // likewise for all extensions

        NSData* video = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileUrl options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
            [error release];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Data has loaded successfully.");
        }

        BOOL success = [video writeToFile:yourpath atomically:NO];

        [fileUrlRequest release];
        if (success) {
             //open your video the way you want
        }
```