# How can I check if a file is an image file without checking the path extension?

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, file-type

I need to differentiate between **text file** and **image file** without taking a look their path extension.

I would like to check if the file is actually the image or not. 
After searching, there is the way to check the mimetype from path extension, however, I would like the solution to verify the file's content itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the type of a file in Cocoa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814463/get-the-type-of-a-file-in-cocoa)

Comment: I've mentioned in the question description that I need the solution that doesn't take a look at their file extension. The solution in the suggested question doesn't answer my need because it consider file extension as a factor to say what file type it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SomeFile.xyz"];
if (image == nil) {
    NSLog(@"This is probably text file");
}
```

If image is nil means the file may be text or another type of file.