# Get file type of given file - based on contents

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, uti

OK, it may sound fairly straightforward but I'm still not sure how to go about it.

I *know* it's possible to check file type based on file extensions, using UTIs (e.g. [Get the type of a file in Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814463/get-the-type-of-a-file-in-cocoa)).

However, I need to be able to get the file type (in more general terms, like "text", "image", "else"), depending on the content.

Is that possible?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One route forward is to call the [`file`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/file.1.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/1/file) command and parse its output, but that is fairly horrible, and I wouldn't do that as it's slow and you are susceptible to changes in the output.

The `file` command uses [a pretty extensive database of byte patterns](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man5/magic.5.html) to test the contents of the file and I would be tempted to implement my own internal version of it, or use [this library](http://filemagic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide.html) (which I think might need some work before it works under OSX).